# jQuery MiniColors Input Style

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-minicolors

How I do to [jQuery MiniColors](https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) respect the class I specify? By example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Name">Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Color</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4"> 
    <input type='text' class='form-control color-picker' id="Color">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the two INPUTS be the same style (form-control), but minicolors mess all the style:

[image: Different form-control]

I think is something do with "theme" option, but I"m unsure about how I do to fix, because I'm using the default "form-control" class from Bootstrap 3.

Someone please, can tell whats I'm doing wrong or how I do to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure.. But I guess you should use minicolors-input class instead of color-picker

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it does not works... and in the samples page, they use the classes "form-control" and "demo", and the "demo" class is just a helper